# Add multi-layered ticklabels to plotly xaxis for timeseries

Tags: r, charts, formatting, plotly

I want to add xaxis labels to a plotly that looks like the attached image. Notice the different tick angles for month and year and the merged year values (I made the plot in excel).

[image]

At present in my plotly I can split the month-year into two lines but is there a way to angle the months at 90degrees and merge the years similar to the excel. Below is some sample data and the current output I get from plotly.

```
library(plotly)
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), 7)
set.seed(42)
values <- rnorm(105, 10, 2)

data.frame(dates = dates, values = values) %>%
  plot_ly(x=~dates, y=~values) %>% 
  add_lines() %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(dtick = "M1", ticklabelmodel = "period" , tickformat = "%b<br>%Y", tickangle = 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

- I don't have access to an R environment, hence answer in python
- use a multi category axis.  This is a 2D array passed as **x** parameter
- update the layout to rotate the text of first part of multi category axis

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range("1-jan-2020", freq="M", periods=23), "value":np.random.uniform(2,5,23)})

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[df["date"].dt.year, df["date"].dt.strftime("%b") ], y=df["value"]))
fig.update_layout(xaxis={"tickangle":-90})
```

[image]

Comment: i used a list to pass xaxis values but now cant get it back the dates back to month ```tibble(dates = dates, values = values) %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(dates)) %>% 
  plot_ly(x=~ list(year, dates), y=~values) %>% 
  add_lines() ```

Comment: if i use a month column the points stack on each other on the month. `tickformat` isnt working for the array.